# Separate data using java String.split() method

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to use the `String.split()` method in the java programming language to retrieve data from a string.
The data in my string is in a weird format. Let me give you an example: let's say I have the following string:

```
String s="My name is      :  John Smith         13   75,5";
```

I need to split the string in such a way that everything (except whitespaces) before `:` goes to a string, then, in what's left, everything (except whitespaces) before the first number to another string, then the first number to another string and the last number to another string, such that, considering the `String s` in my example I would have the following output:

```
My name is
John Smith
13
75,5
```

I tried the following code:

```
data= s.split("\\s*\\:\\s*|\\s+|\\s+");
```

But the output was:

```
My
name
is
John
Smith
13
75,5
```

I've tried many other regular expressions but with no success (I believe that proves how much of a beginner I am with regex...) Can somebody help me?

**Note:** I think it wouldn't be too difficult to write my own split method for my data and maybe it's much better in terms of performance but I would really like to understand how to do this using regex.

Comment: Could you just split on two or more spaces and remove the colon from the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep single spaces, but split on 2+ spaces, the expression looks like this:

```
data= s.split("\\s*\\:\\s*|\\s{2,}");
```

This produces the output that you need ([demo](http://ideone.com/HYgS73)):

```
My name is
John Smith
13
75,5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"\\s*\\:\\s*|\\s+|\\s+"
```

The `|` characters don't do what you think they might. They act as "or", so in your case your regex is matching `\\s+` to the spaces between words, because while they don't match the first section of your regex, they certainly match the second (and third).

Better solution would be something like this:

```
"\\s*\\:\\s*|\\s{2,}"
```

Comment: Ah you're right I was mistakenly using the `|`. Your suggestion needs a little change to `"\\s+\\:?\\s+"` to ignore the whitespaces. Thank you.

Comment: @PML Ah right, forgot those. I'll add them in. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Oh but wait the answer below accounts for the case where there's no space before or after the semicolon. But substituting + for * doesn't seem to work they way I expected...

Comment: @PML Oh, that's a possibility too? Didn't realize that... In that case, his/her answer is correct. You shouldn't need to substitute anything for that answer.

Comment: My mistake. I should have states that more clearly. Thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: @PML No, it's mine, as I should have been able to figure it out based on your example regex. Glad I could help though.